# Trying to create powerautomate flow that will lock a weekly excel workbook every week

Tags: excel, dynamic, power-automate

I create weekly files that are being saved in week specific folders and I want to create a flow that will automatically lock & password protect the file every single week at Friday 8PM. So my problems has two challenges, 1. Locking an excel file w/a password at the 8PM friday deadline & 2. doing it for the new file created every single week.

Comment: You should narrow the scope of your question and post what you've tried or where you are stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you searched on here for vba code? There are some that show how to set passwords etc and others about running at xx time.